# bash passing positional parameters in function

Tags: bash, function, parameters

I have a small problem, please look next code and output, and could you tell me what I miss.
    #!/bin/bash

```
foo () {

echo "Parameter #1 is $1" 

}

foo
```

my output:
[user@host]$ ./test.scr test

Parameter #1 is

Parameter #1 is

Answer (score 1):

functions get their own positional parameters from when they are called.

If you need to pass the scripts arguments to the function use `foo "$@"` (the quotes are important do not forget them).